# Android - Set Drawable To Start of Textview and Center of First Line of Text

Tags: android, textview, font-size

I've very simple page and you can see my horizontal Info icon and Textview on below. You can simply add Info icon as Image Asset to default project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_info"
            tool:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_info" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Aaa bbbb cc dd ee ff ggggg hh kkkkkkkk" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is:

- If text is 1 line: the Info icon should be centre aligned to the text
- If text is more than 1 line: the Info icon should be centre aligned to the
  first line of the text

Currently with this xml; if I use default Font Size and Style of tablet, I see like below. Everything seems perfect:

[image]

But, if I increase the Font Size and Style to maximum from **general settings of tablet**, I see like below. Text and icon are aligned to top:

[image]

Is there any solution that helps for both 2 cases ?